# variable not defined, when clearly I have it defined

Tags: python

I have defined swim_or_wait on else block but I get swim_or_wait not defined. What am I doing wrong? I am learning python.

This is my code:

```py
print("Welcome to Treasure Island.")
print("Your mission is to find the treasure.") 

direction = input("Left or right? ".lower())

if direction == "right":
  print("Game over.")
else:
  swim_or_wait = input("Swim or wait? ".lower())

if swim_or_wait == "swim":
  print("Game Over.")
else:
  door = input("Pick a door. Red, Yellow, or Blue. ".lower())

if door == "red" or door == "blue":
  print("Game Over")
else:
  print("You win!")
```

This is the traceback

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 33, in <module>
    if swim_or_wait == "swim":
NameError: name 'swim_or_wait' is not defined
```

What I expected to happen is if the user enter left, then the code will ask the user swim or wait. etc.

Comment: The variable only gets defined if `direction` is not “right”. **Otherwise it’s undefined.**

Comment: @R__i_ Scope has nothing to do with it.

Comment: The bigger problem is probably that you’ll want to *end* the game instead of just printing “Game over”. If the game actually ended then, the rest would work correctly.

Comment: so to solve this I would have to define the variable outside the condition?

Comment: No, prevent the game from continuing to the next condition when it shouldn’t, because it’s already game over.

Comment: ok, but what if the user chooses the other direction? that's what the else statement is for.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254770/discussion-on-question-by-aka-moosh-variable-not-defined-when-clearly-i-have-it); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: I think it's a good questions with a simple answer of how if-else works

Comment: @Prayson We’ve been over this in all the comments here, and apparently what OP is seeing is not what we’d expect to be seeing. So without more info, this current problem isn’t reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

use exit() function to exit from code once "Game Over". modify the code like this.

```
import sys
print("Welcome to Treasure Island.")
print("Your mission is to find the treasure.") 

direction = input("Left or right? ".lower())

if direction == "right":
  print("Game over.")
  sys.exit()
else:
  swim_or_wait = input("Swim or wait? ".lower())

if swim_or_wait == "swim":
  print("Game Over.")
  sys.exit()
else:
  door = input("Pick a door. Red, Yellow, or Blue. ".lower())

if door == "red" or door == "blue":
  print("Game Over")
  sys.exit()
else:
  print("You win!")
```

Comment: And then the `else` really becomes superfluous and should be omitted.

Comment: I haven't learned what sys.exit() is, please help without adding code that isn't in the example. instead how can I change the code to make it work without adding code I dont know.

Comment: @AKA Without actually exiting, you’d need to indent the following code under the `else` branches. Currently everything after the `if..else` gets executed regardless of whether it went into `if` or `else`. But all the code after it logically belongs into the `else` branch.

Comment: @deceze I thought else statements ends the if condition, for example if this do A, else do B. then if I need another condition to be tested out side of the first, I can simply just create another if statement.

Comment: @AKA Yes, it ends that particular `if..else`, but then happily continues in the “main” flow and check the next `if..else`.

Comment: @deceze so if I assign a value to a variable with the = sign inside of a if/else statement, python doesn't remember that value for the variable for the next conditions?

Comment: @AKA That’s not the problem, Python remembers just fine. But the variable only gets assigned and defined *if* you hit that branch of the `if..else` condition. If you hit the branch where the variable does not get defined, then it doesn’t exist in the code after the `if..else`.

Comment: @deceze, but isn't that what the code is doing? So if the user select "Left" the code will follow the else condition and ask the user for another input. which I have that input assigned.

Comment: @AKA That’s what should happen, yes. If it doesn’t, make that more clear by editing your question and showing us how the game progresses.

Comment: @deceze ok my bad, I thought you guys would know just from reading the code. Im new to this.

Comment: @AKA From just reading your code, we got into the quagmire we’re currently in. It appears that the problem is, that what we expect should happen isn’t actually what you see…!?

Answer (score 1):

After the `if ... else ...` statement is executed, it will continue to execute code with the same indentation below, without terminating at any branch. Consider the following example:

```
if True:
    print('foo')
else:
    print('bar')

print('baz')
```

The flowchart for execution is as follows:

```
[print('bar')] <--no?-- <True> --yes?--> [print('foo')]
      |_______________________________________|
                          ↓
                    [print('baz')]
```

Therefore, the following content will be output:

```
foo
baz
```

We adjust the indentation to ensure that subsequent code will only execute in the else branch, rather than executing regardless of whether the condition in the if statement holds:

<sub>Note: The prompt in your `input()` using `str.lower()` appears to be a typo, and I think what you really want to do may be to make the input string lowercase, so I moved it outside the parentheses.</sub>

```
print("Welcome to Treasure Island.")
print("Your mission is to find the treasure.") 

direction = input("Left or right? ").lower()

if direction == "right":
    print("Game over.")
else:
    swim_or_wait = input("Swim or wait? ").lower()

    if swim_or_wait == "swim":
        print("Game Over.")
    else:
        door = input("Pick a door. Red, Yellow, or Blue. ").lower()

        if door == "red" or door == "blue":
            print("Game Over")
        else:
            print("You win!")
```

This is the simplest repair method, but not the best. If you have learned how to define a function, defining a function and using a return statement can end it earlier:

```
def main():
    print("Welcome to Treasure Island.")
    print("Your mission is to find the treasure.") 

    direction = input("Left or right? ").lower()

    if direction == "right":
        print("Game over.")
        return
    
    swim_or_wait = input("Swim or wait? ").lower()

    if swim_or_wait == "swim":
        print("Game Over.")
        return
    
    door = input("Pick a door. Red, Yellow, or Blue. ").lower()

    if door == "red" or door == "blue":
        print("Game Over")
    else:
        print("You win!")


main()  # don't forget to call it
```

Comment: My question is why can't I have another condition outside of the first? why does everything has to be indented.

Comment: @AKA Because that’s how control flow works. Perhaps observing the execution step by step on https://pythontutor.com would help.